# How do I use this listener

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, list

I have been trying to solve this stupid issue for 9 hours now, and I'm about to cry.

I have a listview and I simply want to detect whether someone long pressed an item. If so, I want to delete the item. So, I used the following code:

```
 listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {

            Log.v(TAG, "LONG CLICKED");


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            contactArrayList.remove(pos);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            return true;
        }

//PLEASE HELP ME I AM GOING TO CRY WHY ISNT THIS WORKING
    });
```

Now, this method gets called the first time, but after doing something like rotating the screen, the long press method **JUST DOESNT GET DETECTED**. If I add another item to the list though, then it **Starts getting detected again**.

So, here's the code that executes when I **do** add an item (which is a contacts name and number):

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            contactUri = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to first row...IDK why
            int NumberColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER); //Int column is the column of the numbers

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(NumberColumn);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if(contactArrayList.size() <= 4) {

                contactArrayList.add(contactName + " - " + contactNumber);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here's my onCreate, although it seems unnecessary:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> contactArrayList;
ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter;
ListView listview;
public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 100; //Request code to make sure it is same in onActivityResult and in startActivityForResult inent
SharedPreferences contacts;
SharedPreferences.Editor contactEditor;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Uri contactUri;
Cursor cursor;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contacts = this.getSharedPreferences("contacts", MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE); //Making a shared preferences


    contactArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactArrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    loadSavedStuff();

    for (String s : contactArrayList){
        Log.d(TAG, "Array List : "+ s);
    }

}

public void loadSavedStuff() {
    //CLEAR CONTENTS OF ARRAYLIST AND GET THEM FROM SHARED PREFERENCE OF CONTACTS SAVED IN ONPAUSE


    if(contacts != null && (contacts.getStringSet("contactSetKey", null) != null)) { //If the shared preferences and the stuff inside
        contactArrayList.clear();
        contactArrayList.addAll(contacts.getStringSet("contactSetKey", null));
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    for (String s : contactArrayList){
        Log.d(TAG, "Array List : "+ s);
    }


}
```

Please help me figure this out. I have spent 9 hours on this and I really need to know *why* its happening and how to fix it. It's weird because after adding an item, the long presses get detected again...

Thanks so so so so so so so much,

Ruchir

Comment: It's weird because after adding an item, the long presses get detected again...I would appreciate anything from anyone. A comment, an answer, ANYTHING HELPS!

Comment: Yes i do like to know where do you set your listener as well

Comment: @Styx Like this: 'listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {' How should I be doing it? What could the problem be? Thanks so much for helping me out!

Comment: Yes @MikeM. is right. Not how but where do you set them. in OnCreate? OnResume?

Comment: @MikeM. In the onActivityResult method

Comment: Now it makes sense! Move it to onCreate() after you reference your ListView.

Comment: @Styx In onActivityResult method

Comment: @Styx Okay, I will try that, but why was the problem happening

Comment: @RuchirBaronia because you only set listener in your onActivityResult which only will trigger when you back from picking a contact. That is why you can only long click when a new contact is added.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in the comment section. We found that the listener is set in onActivityResult which cause the problem as you described earlier.

> **the long press method JUST DOESNT GET DETECTED. If I add another item to the list though, then it Starts getting detected again.**

The listener is set in your onActivityResult which only will trigger when you back from picking a contact. That is why you can only long click when a new contact is added.

Moving the part of code which set the listener to onCreate after you reference the ListView will solve your problem.

To learn more about activity lifecycle and onActivityResult you can refer to [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [Getting a result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Attaching a listener is like telling the view what to do when an event is triggered. You have to only attach once and it will last until the activity is finished, the listener is detach, or a new listener is attach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android destroys everything and rebuilds on configuration change. Your listener may be referencing an old instance of whatever it was called from. You will need to attach/detach the listener. The fact that you are using an anonymous listener doesn't help either.

Comment: The same code runs again and new listener is re-attached. Nothing wrong with anonymous listener.

Comment: When you say runs again? Under what conditions does it run again?

Comment: So how do I do it without anonymous class? Can you show example of how to fix it? Thanks so much, i have been stuck for 10 hours now

Comment: The activity is re-created when screen rotates means the codes in onCreate is re-run and a new listener is re-attached to the ListView again. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia maybe show us where you attach your listener please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm listening to Click and LongClick on items by the following way without adding config to the manifest as the previous answer, in your RecyclerView holder, make it implements implements View.OnLongClickListener, Then in your RecycleViewHolder Const, Add the following :

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

Now Override the method :

```
    @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    Log.i(YourTAG,getLayoutPosition());

    return true;
}
```

You can get the item position by getLayoutPosition and then remove it .

Comment: The problem he is facing have to do with normal ListView implementation not recyclerView

Comment: Why not upgrading to RecyclerView ? it's better, and got a lot of helpers .

Comment: It is like a guy asking you how to fix a bicycle and you replied by asking him to get a car instead.

Comment: The car is better and much safer :p .